# How do I get my /server-status stats to display on my apache2 installation?

Tags: apache, apache2

I copied the relevant lines over from another installation but it doesn't work here.  I get a 404 generated by the word press that's installed on the server.

```
<Location /server-status>
   SetHandler server-status
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from [my ip]
</Location>
```

I used to visit http://[old server ip]/server-status and it worked fine.  Now I just get a 404 coming out of the wordpress that's installed on the new server.

Is this what happens if the proper mods are not installed in this installation?  How can I tell?  How can I trouble shoot this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that this config had to go in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf

From what I read it seemed to me like it could also go in apache2.conf or the individual site config file but those didn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the LoadModule for mod_status. On debian/ubuntu, use a2enmod. If you manage your config directly, just add the LoadModule for mod_status.

Comment: No it wasn't that, see below.